# Marginal probabilities of independent variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Having an old book of exercises without any solution,explaining the concept to me would be helpful.

Two independent variables X,Y are getting values from x∈0,1 and y∈0,1,2.The joint variable (X,Y) has a distribution as P(X=x,Y=y)=K(x+y).

Find the values of X,Y and (X,Y).

My work so far:I have found the marginal values

- P(X=0,Y=0)=0
- P(X=0,Y=1)=k
- P(X=0,Y=2)=2k
- P(X=1,Y=0)=k
- P(X=1,Y=1)=2k
- P(X=1,Y=2)=3k

Their sum must be 1, so each possibility is 0(1/6),k(1/3),2k(1/3),3k(1/6).If assuming i am correct so far then K=1/9 (but what does K mean and what's P(X) and P(Y)?

Comment: The two variables are _not_ independent if by independence you mean _stochastic_ Independence: that is, (for discrete variables), $$P(X=x, Y=y) =P(X=x)P(Y=y)~ \text{for all choices of}~ x~\text{and}~ y.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $K=1/9$ for the reason you cited.   $K$ is just a constant.

Next, by the Law of Total Probability

$$P(X{=}x)~{=~P(X{=}x,Y{=}0)+P(X{=}x,Y{=}1)+P(X{=}x,Y{=}2)\\=~\phantom{K~((x)+(x+1)+(x+2))~\mathbf 1_{x\in\{0,1\}}}\\=~\underline{\phantom{\tfrac13(x+1)}}~\mathbf 1_{x\in\{0,1\}}}$$

And similarly:

$$P(Y{=}y)~{=~{P(X{=}0,Y{=}y)+P(X{=}1,Y{=}y)}\\=~\phantom{K~((y)+(1+y))~\mathbf 1_{y\in\{0,1,2\}}}\\=~\underline{\phantom{\tfrac 19(2y+1)}}~\mathbf 1_{y\in\{0,1,2\}}}$$